# how to close a file and delete that image file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

```
Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename;
Imagepath = "D:\\Shop\\ShopMonkey\\Images" + Imagename;
FileUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(@"D:\ShopMonkey_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images", Imagename));

objUser.UploadImagePath = Imagepath;
objUser.UploadImagename = Imagename;

System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Imagepath);

System.Drawing.Image bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(50, 50, null, IntPtr.Zero);
 ThumbNailPath = "D:\\ShopMonkey_Web_21-6-12\\ShopMonkey\\ThumbNails" + Imagename;
bmp1.Save(Path.Combine(@"D:\ShopMonkey_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\ThumbNails", Imagename));
objUser.UploadThumbnailPath = ThumbNailPath;
```

How to delete the image and thumbnail in other function? (Is it necessary to close that first or not?)

Comment: You've just created img1 and bmp1.  Are you trying to delete `Imagename` from disk?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: ya if the image present in that disk means delete that both image and thumbnail..otherwise come out from that loop(its neccessary to use file operation r not??)...here im using fileupload so its gettin too much of trouble..please help me friend

Comment: please friend guide me..waiting for ur reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're trying to delete a file on disk if it already exists for this user upon asp.net upload of an image by that same user again.

This method will delete both image and thumbnail if they exist.

Keep your image creation activities separate from your image clean up activities to keep your intent clear and your code maintainable.

```
    // replace with an entry loaded from a config file    
    const string ImageRoot = @"D:\ShopMonkey_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey"; 
    // replace this is your user instance
    object user = new object(); 
    string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename;
    string uploadImagePath = Path.Combine(ImageRoot, "Images", Imagename);
    string thumbnailPath = Path.Combine(ImageRoot, "ThumbNails", Imagename);
    objUser.UploadImagePath = uploadImagePath;
    objUser.UploadImagename = Imagename;
    objUser.UploadThumbnailPath = thumbnailPath;
    // delete both if they exist
    if (File.Exists(uploadImagePath))
        File.Delete(uploadImagePath);
    if (File.Exists(thumbnailPath))
          File.Delete(thumbnailPath);
    // replace this with your uploaded file details
    object fileInfo = new object(); 
    using (System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(uploadImagePath)) {
          img1.Save(uploadImagePath);
          using (System.Drawing.Image bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(50, 50, null, IntPtr.Zero)) {
            bmp1.Save(thumbnailPath);
          }
          FileUpload.SaveAs(uploadImagePath);
    }
```

Comment: ho to check size of image from fileupload and how to check whether selected file is image